# How to pipe a remote file to stdout over scp or sftp?

Tags: ssh, scp, cat, sftp

Using ssh, it is easy to print the contents of a file using

```sh
ssh host 'cat file.txt'
```

When ssh is disabled, and only SFTP is enabled, running the previous command gives the following error:

> This service allows sftp connections only.

To work-around this issue, I could create a temporary file using `scp` or `sshfs` (as shown below), but that looks really ugly. What is the proper way to print the contents of a remote file when SSH is disabled?

```sh
mkdir tmpdir
sshfs host: tmpdir
cat tmpdir/file.txt
fusermount -u tmpdir

# This does not work! scp -v host:file.txt . shows
# "Sink: This service allows sftp connections only."
scp host:file.txt .
cat file.txt
rm file.txt
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Curl can display the file the same way cat would. No need to delete the file since it simply displayed the output unless you tell it to do otherwise.

```
curl -u username:password sftp://hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

If you use public key authentication:

```
curl -u username: --key ~/.ssh/id_rsa --pubkey sftp://hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

If you use the default locations, then `--key` and `--pubkey` can be omitted:

```
curl -u username: sftp://hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

The user name can also be a part of the URL, so the final result looks very close to the ssh command:

```
curl sftp://username@hostname/path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for! I have edited your answer to expand on public-key authentication, it turns out that the syntax is very similar to the ssh/sshfs syntax. If the curl command fails with "curl: (51) SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK", just add the `-k` flag (`--insecure`).

Comment: #2 fails with `no URL specified!`, #3 fails with `(67) Login denied`. It works when entering password manually :(

Answer (score 40):

For people who can run `scp`, you can do this:

```
scp remotehost:/path/to/remote/file /dev/stdout
```

Comment: Neither method works. The first one is equivalent to the one-liner `sftp username@hostname:/path/to/file.txt /dev/stdout` and results in "Couldn't write to "/dev/stdout": Illegal seek". The second command fails, and shows the error that is shown at the bottom of my question.

Comment: The SFTP form works fine for me. It may depend on what version of the ssh software you're using. Regarding scp, I did say "if scp works". You established in your question that the server was not permitting you to perform scp, so naturally the scp command would fail for you.

Comment: `ssh -V` gives `OpenSSH_6.6.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014`. scp fails because it uses ssh under the hood, and ssh is disabled (as a security measure, see e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh)

Comment: I get `scp: local ftruncate "/dev/stdout": Invalid argument` `scp: write local "/dev/stdout": Illegal seek`.  I have `openssh-client 1:9.6p1-4` (Debian).

Comment: @alx-recommendscodidact The "local ftruncate" error is emitted by the SFTP file transfer code when it tries to write to an existing file. Modern versions of `scp` can use `sftp` under the hood to do the file transfer, and can emit that error. Try using scp with the "-O" (capital-O) option to use the legacy scp protocol.

Comment: @Kenster Thanks!  It (`-O`) works.  :)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu I was able to open the remote directory in Files GUI, then "Open in Local Terminal"

At this point I was navigated to a funny path looking like `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=qweqwe.synology.me/Prod_Backup/DB`

From there I could read and pipe files similar to local file systems.

Unfortunately the speed was not adequate for my needs (~200 KB/s).

Answer (score 0):

With `lftp`:

```
lftp -e 'set cmd:show-status 0; cat -b remote/file' sftp://user@host < /dev/null
```

(`</dev/null` to force it to be non-interactive).